# Extra List of Figures Page

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm running into an issue with my dissertation. I'm using a template created to format my dissertation according to the University's guidelines. When I format it using the `twoside` argument for the class, I get my list of figures and List of Tables pages each with an extra page afterward saying `List of Figures - Continued`, but there is nothing else on the page. This only happens with the `twoside` argument.

Comment: Package `emptypage`?

Comment: @Johannes_B nailed it. Want to make it an answer?